# Can WordPress install on IIS and how?

Tags: iis, wordpress, hosting

Can wordpress install on a IIS hosting?
If yes, which is better and more simple, on IIS6 or IIS7?
And how to install it on IIS?

Comment: Don't see why people are downvoting, it's a legitimate question

Comment: possibly the 'not-programming-related police

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into using the [Web Platform Installer Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx) which supports PHP.  The featured [web apps page](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/gallery/) has WordPress as its top option